# Chatbot response on wrong user input

Tags: facebook, conversational-interface, chatbots

Trying my hands on [facebook messenger chatbot](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform) implementation.

The bot is integrated to facebook pages and interacts to user via a series of options and preset carousel templates which the user can select, good examples ICYMI are CNN and Poncho bots on messenger.

We have a scenario where our bot prompts the user to enter some details ,lets say , his year of birth.

The conversation is as follows :

**Bot** : Welcome Dude,what do you want to read today (horoscope) (news) (recipes)

**User** : ...selects horoscope...

**Bot** : Please enter your year of birth

**User** : ABCDEF

**Bot** : ??

At this point , IMHO we have two options since the user has entered an invalid input, we validate the user input against the expected input and say

**Bot** : Err.... that is not a valid year, can you try again?

or

**Bot** : Oops, that is something that i dont understand . You could rather try any of these (horoscope) (news) (recipes)

Which would be more apt for the given scenario in the conversational thread?

First option would *hold* the user in place till he enters the proper year . Which i feel i kind of detrimental in case he wants to break off voluntarily.

Choosing the second could *break* the thread and make the user start all over again  , which could cause some annoyance.

Question -

- Should the bot wait on the user till the user enters a expected input
  ?
- Or, should the bot just acknowledge the wrong input and show user
  other options?

Awaiting your suggestions !

Answer (score 2):

Don't pretend this isn't a bot answering. You need the user's answer to deliver the service. You need to give an answer that doesn't make them feel stupid. You can make it humorous: "Hey, I'm only a robot, I need things simple. I really need the year you were born." or "I need your help to get this right. Can you give me the year you were born, something like "1992"?"

Then have a time out. If nothing new has been typed, say something like "Maybe you've decided you'd like something else? You can still get a [horoscope] or you could look at [news] or [recipes]."

If the user continues to type in nonsense, they are either trolling or have problems, and at some point you can either say, "Whoa, pal, I'm in overload here. Why don't I take you back to the home page?" or just stop responding.

Comment: yup, +1 for Don't pretend this isn't a bot answering. But  the question was in case of an erraneous input , should the bot wait til lthe user enters a correct input or acknowlege the wrong input and show the list of other options that the user can peruse ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd give the user **both options** to avoid they'll get stuck in the process or get annoyed restarting over and over. Including an example of the expected answer (like someone already mentioned) is always a good idea.

Example:

> *"That doesn't seem like a valid year. Type a year in numbers like '1990' to see your horoscope or change to (news) (recipes)."*